# Twitter Callback and Login Using Jtwitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

```
 public class TwitterActivity extends Activity 
    {
        private Twitter twitter;
        private OAuthProvider provider;
        private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer;

        String CONSUMER_KEY = "abcdefgh";
        String CONSUMER_SECRET = "abcdefgh";
        String CALLBACK = "twitterapp://connect"; 


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            askOAuth();
        }

        private void askOAuth() {
            try {
                consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
                provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                                                    "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                                                    "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
                String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please authorize this app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(APP, e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

            super.onNewIntent(intent);

            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK)) {

                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                try {
                    // this will populate token and token_secret in consumer
                    provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifier);

                    // TODO: you might want to store token and token_secret in you app settings!!!!!!!!
                    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(consumer.getToken(), consumer.getTokenSecret());

                    // initialize Twitter4J
                    twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
                    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

                    // create a tweet
                    Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    String tweet = "#OAuth working! " + d.toLocaleString();

                    // send the tweet
                    twitter.updateStatus(tweet);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(APP, e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }
    }


P.S.: I have used these api's 
  [1]: https://github.com/punitmg/Twitter-Test-App
  [2]: https://github.com/grantland/twitter-android-sdk
  [3]: https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/
```

By using all these API's i am able to tweet successfully. But unfortunately the below mentioned 2 screens are appearing in all the above 3 cases..

All i want is to finish() or close the below two screen when my tweet is completed.

```
So .... plz guide me if i was wrong ...
```

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: I dont want the above 2 screens they remain in the stack whenever i tweet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force login second time to resolve this issue,

So just add the **force_login=true** in your twitter authorize url.

I mean just change the below line of code in **TwitterApp.java** class (if you have a class file with different name then search in your project with **DefaultOAuthProvider**)

```
mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
        "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?force_login=true");
```

after adding **force_login=true** webview loading issue will be resolve but every time you need to enter login and password.